# Order By Clause seems to be not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a full-text search that utilizes TOP and Order By.  I've used this same query in another database and my order always stays the same.  For some reason on a different database, the order always seems to change a little.  Not a lot, but just a little.  Here is what it looks like

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT CandidateID, [Resume], FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) AS num

       FROM dbo.tblCandidates  WHERE (CONTAINS(([resume]), @SearchItem))

) AS a 
WHERE num > @start
```

Can anyone think of a reason that the Order By clause wouldn't always work in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: `CreatedDate` contains duplicates?

Comment: I'm curious if your other database had the `ORDER BY` column indexed. Have you tried adding an `ORDER BY num` below your WHERE?

Comment: Do you mean the order of the results changes when you run the query multiple times on the same data?

Comment: Nikola - well, I thought that too so I had added a full-text index column (identity) to the order by and that didn't work either.

Comment: Dean - Yes, it's odd... I run the same query over and over and each time the results change slightly (in terms of order)  Jason, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Do you actually do `order by num`? It's missing from the query.

Comment: Hey Jason.. that fixed it!!!  Thank you so much!!  I don't see where there are any indexes on the Created Date column in the other database though? hmmm  It works though! (I guess this is bad programming to celebrate something working without understanding why...uuugghhhh)

Comment: Order of rows is not guaranteed unless you specify it using `order by`. `Row_number() over()` does not force order of rows by itself; it is only assigning numbers. Append `order by num` to the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't HAVE an `ORDER BY` clause (the one inside the `OVER()` clause is used to determine `ROW_NUMBER()` and does not usually have any influence whatsoever of the order of the output). If you've observed a specific order from this query on other systems, it has been purely coincidental and should not be relied upon. If you want a specific order, you need to add `ORDER BY` to the outer query, no matter what you think it should do or what you have observed elsewhere.

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT CandidateID, [Resume], FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) AS num

       FROM dbo.tblCandidates  WHERE (CONTAINS(([resume]), @SearchItem))

) AS a 
WHERE num > @start
ORDER BY num;
```

Comment: thank you Aaron and Michael... that was it.  I really appreciate it.